# Looping function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I have a table called nba that has the form

```
NBA(date DATE, team1 varchar(30), score1 int, team2 varchar(30), score2 int);
```

where team1 is always the winner and team2 is always the loser. Example part of the table:

```
    date    |         team1          | score1 |         team2          | score2 
------------+------------------------+--------+------------------------+--------
 2013-10-29 | Indiana Pacers         |     97 | Orlando Magic          |     87
 2013-10-29 | Miami Heat             |    107 | Chicago Bulls          |     95
 2013-10-29 | Los Angeles Lakers     |    116 | Los Angeles Clippers   |    103
 2013-10-30 | Cleveland Cavaliers    |     98 | Brooklyn Nets          |     94
 2013-10-30 | Philadelphia 76ers     |    114 | Miami Heat             |    110
```

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a team, loops through the game list, and transfers the "title" to any team that beats that winning team. For example, the beginning team could be 'Miami Heat'. The next team that beats the heat will be the champion, taking the title away from the heat. The next team to beat that team will pass the title on them, etc. So if the Magic beat the Heat and the Lakers then beat the Magic, the lakers would currently hold the title. I want to iterate through the table and complete this 'passing' of the title all the way through the end and return the last team to have the title at the end of the list.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
--Declare function and specify argument as a team that holds title at beginning

CREATE FUNCTION findChamp(thechamp varchar(30)) RETURNS void as 

$func$
-- Set current champ to argument passed in 
DECLARE
        r nba%rowtype;
        champ varchar(30) = thechamp;
BEGIN
        FOR r in Select * from nba
        LOOP
        IF team2 = champ -- If the champ lost
                champ = team1; -- Champ is now the team it lost to
        END IF;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN champ; -- Return the final champ
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I'm new to writing functions in postgres and don't think this is too sound. I'm currently getting an error of

```
psql:function.psql:16: ERROR:  missing "THEN" at end of SQL expression
LINE 10:   champ = team1;
```

. Where am I going wrong? I've added THEN statements in multiple places and none seem to fix the problem, I believe I'm off significantly on syntax somewhere. Any pointers are appreciated

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: You should look into data normalization.  You should have a separate table that holds the teams rather than replicating the team name in each game's row.

Comment: The then needs to go after team2 = champ. However, you have another issue, which is you can't return champ when you function is declared to return void.

Answer (score 0):

Critiqued solution:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION findChamp(date)  RETURNS varchar as
$func$
DECLARE
    r nba%rowtype;
    champ varchar(30) = 'Miami Heat';
BEGIN
    FOR r in Select * from nba where date >= $1
    LOOP
    IF (r.team2 = champ)
        THEN champ = r.team1;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN champ;
END;
$func$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```